# Writing a variable to a .txt file using Batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a very simple variable saver. I want varset.bat to save the variable "var" to var.txt and I want varview.bat to read it back to me. var.txt only reads "" no matter what I put.

```
varset.bat                                         
@echo off                                            
cd C:/Jual/JualVAR >nul                                                     
set /p var = jual-                                                          
echo "%var%"> var.txt                              
cd C:/Jual >nul                                  

varview.bat                                                   
@echo off                                                       
cd C:/Jual/JualVAR >nul                                  
FOR /F %%i IN (var.txt) DO @echo %%i                                 
cd C:/Jual >nul
```

Comment: `set /p var = jual-` --> `set /p var=jual-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put a space in a variable's name in bat.

if you use :

```
set /p var = jual-
```

then the varname will be `%var %`

so, if you want use `%var%` set the var without space :

```
set /p var=jual-
```